# Inserting data to table that its primary key is combined from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I combine these column as primary key.

```
room_no, type
```

When I insert new data for example, `0001 01`.

And then I insert `0001 02`.

It can not be done. It said duplicate primary key. Why it duplicate although I define 2 columns as a primary key.

Comment: How is your table defined? I.e. `describe table`

Comment: room_no(PK) char(4),type(PK) char(2)

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is same as compsite primay key working.

You can read this article:- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-great-primary-key-debate/1045050

Comment: Dunno but i get a feeling that the article misses a very important point. The point that it seems to miss is that even if u intend using a surrogate key as the primary key instead of the natural key, the entity will still have the natural key as a part of the entity, except it would not be the primary key. for instance when he says that u cannot enter a record until value is known, u cannot enter a record until value is known even in case of a surrogate key because we are just not interested in RELATING DATA USING KEYS but also in the REAL DATA which the entity holds which is the natural key

Answer (score 4):

Just a thought:

- Have you defined indexes seperately on them?
- Have you defined each key individually as unique?

Comment: How can I do that ? I use phpmyadmin

Comment: CREATE TABLE ROOM (
  room_no char (4),
  type char(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (room_no, type)
);